# How can I take every combination of vectors for the numpy array in the equation shown

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

```
numpy.dot(nparray[1],nparray[2])/((np.sum(nparray[1]))*(np.sum(nparray[2]))
```

I want to implement this so that it does it for all of the vectors in my numpy array. How can I go about doing this? I'm assuming that it'll use itertools.combinations but after that I'm lost. In the equation above, I'm using the first and the second vector but I'd like to do that for all the combinations of vectors. Is it possible to have this labelled?

edit*
If you have a way of implementing this without itertools, that works too it seems from the comments below that isn't the method I should be using.

Comment: I guess you actually have a list of arrays which you want then to use `itertools.combinations`onto it and then apply that formula over the previously obtained combinations.

Comment: By vector do you mean columns of an array?

Comment: could you show an example of how to do this? I'm not sure how to use itertools.combination either. And to PERCUSSE, yes I do.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use `itertools` over a numpy ndarray extracting a vector. You could use a list of integers as a proxy for each column.

Comment: Then thats my problem. I have to extract each column and its pair and then have python insert into the eq. above.

Comment: You need to explain more on "labelling". This is regarding this question and your previous one as well. NumPy doesn't do well with labellings and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of indexes as a proxy and itertools as follows

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

N = 5  # size of your vector
M = 5  # number of vectors
a = np.random.rand(M,N)

index = range(M)  # using an index to be a proxy to be able to use itertools

for i, j in itertools.combinations(index, 2):
    print(np.dot(a[:,i], a[:,j])  # we're accessing the columns of a
```

Now, instead of printing inside the for loop you call your function (which you should probably define as a proper python function).

Comment: do I just replace the np.dot with the equation that I need?

Comment: yes, basically I just wrote your numerator. Shows how to do it already.

Comment: I understand your use of the index, but how do I convert a dataset that its already given and index it? Because your code depends on me using a random nparray, while my problem is I'm trying to do it on a dataset

Comment: Did not understand the question. If you're given a dataset (which I don't know what you mean by that, you're not defining that in your original question and your nparray looks like a rank 2 numpy ndarray) as a numpy matrix assigned into a variable you just use that variable. Here I have used a random matrix `a` for testing purposes.

Comment: Basically, I already have a matrix that is set, not a random matrix, so I can't create variables necessary for the matrix. e.g. the random matrix     a    is already given to me. So how do I assign the variables to that matrix?

Comment: Just change the calls to the matrix `a` in the for loop with your matrix and replace the `M` inside the `range` with the number of columns you have.